# Find out if Android device is portrait or landscape for normal usage?

Tags: android, default, landscape, portrait

Is there anyway to find out if a device is portrait or landscape by default? In that I mean how you normally use the device.

Most phones have a portrait screen for normal usage but is there some flag for finding that out?

Comment: Do you mean to find on application run time to check weather device is landscape or portrait?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check device natural (default) orientation on Android (i.e. get landscape for e.g., Motorola Charm or Flipout)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553650/how-to-check-device-natural-default-orientation-on-android-i-e-get-landscape)

Answer (score 179):

You can do this by:

**For Lanscape**

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

**For Portrait**

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Check: [Configuration.orientation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation)

Comment: This doesn't work for me when one of my activities is locked to a particular orientation in the Manifest. For example, if it's locked to "Portrait", that it's going to return  Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT even though my device is a landscape tablet.

Comment: Working like a champ in 2017.

Comment: @jrequejo Maybe use the gyroscope data?

Comment: Working like a champ in 2018. I used a Kotlin **when** statement to make the syntax cleaner.

Answer (score 10):

It's **simple**, Just a `If-Else` block:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    // landscape
} else {
    // portrait
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
package com.android.portraitandlandscape;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PortraitLandScape extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();

    Log.v("log_tag", "display width is "+ width);
    Log.v("log_tag", "display height is "+ height);

    if(width<height){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device is in portrait mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device is in landscape  mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }

 }
}
```

You can try this code for checking whether device is in landscape or in portrait.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Codeversed, whose excellent Answer is very close to working (but does NOT as shown), I have a `MainActivity` that works well. All that need be done is move `.enable` to where it can be executed OUTSIDE the `on` block, such as immediately after declaration of `myOrientationEventListener`.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.OrientationEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public static boolean PORTRAIT_MODE = true;
    OrientationEventListener myOrientationEventListener ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
        {
            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation)
            {
                PORTRAIT_MODE = ((orientation < 100) || (orientation > 280));
                Log.w("Orient", orientation + " PORTRAIT_MODE = " + PORTRAIT_MODE);
            }
        };
        Log.w("Listener", " can detect orientation: " + myOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation() + " ");
        myOrientationEventListener.enable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your actvity, do this:

```
if(getRequestedOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
```

for example...

Comment: won't work if you have `android:screenOrientation="portrait|landscape"` set in the manifest on the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will help but this is a quick example I wrote that will show you how to have a listener...which will allow you to figure out which orientation you are in.

```
...textviewOrientation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    myOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, 
              SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL){

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int arg0) {

         textviewOrientation.setText("Orientation: " + String.valueOf(arg0));
         myOrientationEventListener.enable();


             if ((arg0 < 100) || (arg0 > 280)){

                 setRequestedOrientation(
                     ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

             } else {

                 setRequestedOrientation(
                     ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

             }


        }

    };...


...@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    myOrientationEventListener.disable();
}...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Solved it by comparing values of rotation and orientation. There is no need to use sensors or any listeners, just call `isDefaultLandscape` method whenever you wish.

```
private boolean isDefaultLandscape(final Context context)
{
    Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int rotation = display.getRotation();
    int orientation = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    switch (rotation)
    {
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        {
            return orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        }
        default:
        {
            return orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Current orientation
public boolean landscape = false;

public boolean isLandscape(){

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

    if(width<height){
        landscape = false;
    }
    else{
        landscape = true;
    }

    return landscape;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isPortraitMode() {
    int orientation = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
      return false;
    }
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
      return true;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "isPortraitMode returning false by default");
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).