# wrap_content or match_parent do not give the correct result

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Friends, I'm trying to set height of view1 to the height of the filled text textView1, but it doesn’t work. view1 is thus infinitely long and exceeds the height of the text, occupies the entire screen, but I need to the end of the text.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cv">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:weightSum="3"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
         <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_with_color"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Не следует, однако забывать, что начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки новых предложений. С другой стороны реализация намеченных плановых заданий представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки форм развития."
            android:gravity="top"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

rectangle_with_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#E41300" />
</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the issue can u say in few words ?

Comment: @PrajwalW i think the height of the view should not exceed the height of textview ,it should be the size of the data in textview not completely filling layout

Comment: That means you want to stop the red color bar alongside the end of text. Bt now its occupying the entire scree ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fixed your bug. Please use this code below:**

```
<View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:background="@drawable/blank_checkbox"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"/> //make this change
```

> You need to set alignBottom property to mark its end.

**As per documentation:**

> alignBottom: Makes the bottom edge of this view match the bottom edge
>   of the given anchor view ID. Accommodates bottom margin.

Comment: thanks, i also recommend this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6874204/6334053

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cv">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_with_color"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Не следует, однако забывать, что начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки новых предложений. С другой стороны реализация намеченных плановых заданий представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки форм развития."
            android:gravity="top" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[image: ScreenShot]