# make textEdit fill the width in Flex 4.5

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

how do I create a component in Flex 4.5 (using it for android..) that has a textInput and to its right a button, such that the button has fixed size and the textInput expands to fill the remaining space of the parent of the component?

this is the component..

```
<s:HGroup>
    <s:TextInput width="????"/>
    <s:Button width="37" height="37" />
</s:HGroup>
```

of course I don't know what to put in the width.. should I also specify a width for the HGroup?

Comment: if I put 100% it overflows the width of the screen..

Answer (score 1):

Flex determines relative sizes based on the parent of the child.

If you don't give the parent group a width then the TextInput has no idea what it's supposed to be filling to 100%.

```
<s:HGroup width="100%">
    <s:TextInput width="100%"/>
    <s:Button width="37" height="37" />
</s:HGroup>
```

As a side note in response to the "set them both to 100%" answers. 
Flex will allow you to set more than one percentage width to 100%. The 2 will end up being equally weighted. SO

```
<s:HGroup width="100%">
    <s:TextInput width="100%"/>
    <s:Button width="100%"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

will result in 2 components which both take up half the screen.

```
<s:HGroup width="100%">
    <s:TextInput width="200%"/>
    <s:Button width="100%"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

Will result in a TextInput which is twice as wide as the Button

If you want to set percentage based heights and width from ActionSript instead of MXML you need to say `textInput.percentWidth = 100;`

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:HGroup width="100%">
  <s:TextInput width="width" />
  <s:Button width="37" />
</s:Group>
```

here

```
width = [[android screen width (or group width) - 37 ] / android screen width (or group width) ] * 100
```

its in percentage..

or try setting both to `100%`.. that maybe the problem.

**EDIT:**

just get your screen dimensions in your app.. Here is the link to the question .. 
[How to get screen dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height)

Comment: sorry but I don't understand.. how can I set both to 100%? that defeats the purpose.. and the percentage based one doesn't make sense if the screen changes size (it does)

Comment: u can get the size of the screen dimensions in ur app.. check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   <fx:Script>

        <![CDATA[
        import spark.components.Button;

        private function onCreate():void
        {
        var yourButton:Button = new Button();
        yourButton.width = 37;
        yourButton.x = 10;
        yourButton.y = 100;
        text.addChild(yourButton);
        }
]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:TextInput borderVisible="true" id="text" height="100%" width="100%" creationComplete="onCreate()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of both the `HGroup` and the `TextInput` to 100%.

If you don't specify 100% width on the `HGroup` then it will be given a default, static width which might be wider than the width of your screen.

```
<s:HGroup width="100%">
    <s:TextInput width="100%" />
    <s:Button width="37" height="37" />
</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: I had tried this and it didn't work.. any idea why? possible causes?

Comment: Ensure that all containers (and parent containers) from your `TextInput` to your `Application` have a width specified - any container without a width specified will be set to their default size and will prevent children from resizing properly.