# Bitmap ImageView, inside a HorizontalScrollView. How to fit the HorizontalScrollView Height with the bitmap?

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, imageview, horizontalscrollview

I have a Horizontal Scroll View, and inside it i have a ImageView. This imageview has a Bitmap with high width and low height.

I want the bitmap to fill the height of the horizontal scrollview, and I want to scroll the bitmap from left to right.

I tried to use this code, but it doesn't work. It creates two spaces on left and right, these spaces are black. These spaces are from the ImageView... so... the bitmap has less width than the ImageView

```
        HorizontalScrollView wvScroll = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
        wvScroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 
        iv.setImageBitmap(Util.getRemoteImage("http://mywebsite.com/90.gif"));
        //iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        wvScroll.addView(iv);
        wvScroll.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        mainLayout.addView(wvScroll);
```

what am i doing wrong? I also tryed with `iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));` but it doesn't works, Same result.

EDIT:

I also tryed with `ScaleType.CENTER_CROP` and it doesn't works fine. The bitmap has higher height than the ImageView, because some pixels lost on top and bottom of the bitmap.

Comment: Quite often if the view is larger than the image, you want to set `android:adjustViewBounds` or `setAdjustViewBounds(boolean)` to true to make the bounds wrap the image content. That should get rid of the black spaces you're seeing.

Comment: oh... unfortunatelly it doesn't works... now i have BLACK spaces on top and bottom of the bitmap

Comment: Right, that indicates your image is smaller than the actual height of the HorizontalScrollView, which means you want to *upscale* your image at runtime (I kind of missed that statement in the question). The only scale type that enables upscaling is `FIT_XY`, but in order for that to work properly, you need to set the correct dimensions to the ImageView. In other words: calculate the size the image and ImageView should be (keeping aspect ratio etc) and adjust the layout parameters accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to approach this in the simplest way. **I'd set the width of the scroll view the same as the screen width**. The height doesn't matter as much because you're assuming the height will fit in the screen(At least that's what I gather from your question).

From what I remember scroll-views will scroll anything bigger than than the actual screen or anything that is bigger than the specified scroll-width or scroll-height its given.

**This might help you get started with getting the respectable screen sizes -**  [Get Screen width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height)

Of course since different devices have different screen sizes - you'd have to do this "pro-grammatically".

Would this sort of implementation work for you?