# RelativeLayout weight

Tags: android, android-layout

In a layout resource XML, I have 3 RelativeLayout(s) which are inside a main RelativeLayout. The view will be shown vertically. These 3 RelativeLayout() are set next to each other, and I want them to fill the whole screen, doesnt matter what will be the screen size. My, layout view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backg"
 >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_mr_image"
    android:src="@drawable/temp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/r1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/r1bg"
    android:layout_weight="1"

     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/txt_mr_right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/txt_mr_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="S"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/txt_mr_right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/txt_mr_right"
        android:text="T"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/r3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I set `weight=1` and `layout_width=0dp` for each relativeLayout and this technique works with buttons, I thought the same will be with relativeLayout, seems my thoughts were wrong. Any idea?

UPD1: I have added an image of what I would like to have

[image]

Comment: I've done what i was looking for, thanks for comments

Comment: Please share that as an answer. Many curious fellows would like to know how did you achieve it.

Comment: Please check your question. It may mislead a reader that you want `FrameLayout` as a group view, where you want the children `RelativeLayout` of images to overlay one over the other. However, FYKI, if you can achieve this overlaying with `RelativeLayout` as well if all it's children have match_parent both on `layout_width` and `layout_height` without specifying the relation between each other. Orientation and Weighting are the properties of `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`RelativeLayout` does not pay attention to `android:layout_weight`. (That's a property of [`LinearLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html), but not of [`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html).)

You should be able to get the layout you want with a much simpler view hierarchy. It's not clear what you are trying to do, since the last two `RelativeLayout`s are empty. If you need a purely vertical organization, I'd suggest using `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`.

**EDIT** Based on your edit, it looks like you want a horizontal layout of three compound views, each one clickable. I think something like the following will work:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <!-- First column -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstColumn"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="..." />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="text 1"
            . . . />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Second column -->
    <LinearLayout . . . >
        . . .
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If the contents of the buttons aren't correct, you can replace the second-level `LinearLayout` views with `RelativeLayout` if that helps organize the layout better.

Comment: I do have elements inside relativeLayout which has to be positioned in exact ways, it will be kind of a custom clickalble element with images and etc. As my coding knewledge is poor

Comment: @Daler - If you provide more details about the layout you want (a sketch or screen shot would be great), we can help you achieve it. Note also that a vertical `LinearLayout` can contain nested layouts to provide horizontal organization on whatever rows need it.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, i have updated my post you can see what i would like to have. I want to make each relativeLayout clickable, so they will act as a button. all three has the same design with different image types and texts

Comment: @Daler - I see you already accepted my answer, but I edited it to suggest how I would approach what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: it is ok, i made it a little bit different, RelativeLayout->LinearLayout->Relativelayout. In my case i have to go this way as I have to position elements.

Answer (score 8):

RelativeLayouts do not support weight. You need to use a LinearLayout as a parent container if you want to use weights.

Comment: what if the parent is relativeLayout? and i can add the rest relativeLayouts inside the linearLayout. A little bit hardcore but possible

Comment: I guess you could have a RelativeLayout -> LinearLayout -> RelativeLayout x 3, but i'm not sure what that would accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is very simple. I have been looking for weight distribution in relative layout.

It's a small trick for all these kind situations.

Use LinearLayout with    **android:orientation="horizontal"**

Comment: Are you sure that `android:orientation` is a property of `RelativeLayout` ? Brother, that attribute belongs to `LinearLayout`. What about scrolling? That is given by `HorizontalScrollView`. Please at least elaborate the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Horizontally` oriented `LinearLayout Manager` in the `Recycler View`, and place each `RelativeLayout` in each item, of its `Adapter`.

**The Link: [How to build a Horizontal ListView with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460399/787399)**

If your `RelativeLayouts` are set to a fixed width and height, that is to the size of the Screen, that you can get from `DisplayMatrics`, that will be OK.

**The Link: [Get Screen width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4744499/787399)**

If the contents of your RelativeLayouts are different, then you can use `getItemViewType()` method.

**Please see: [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)**

Happy Coding :-)