# Horizontal ListView not updating

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, notifydatasetchanged, horizontallistview

I'm developing an app that has an `HorizontalListview`, currently I'm using `TwoWayView` lib, and everything works fine, but when it has an item changed, the `listview` try to reconstruct the view, but nothing changes, here is the code:

```
if (mHorizontalListViewUsersInChat.getAdapter() != null) {
    usersInChatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mHorizontalListViewUsersInChat.invalidate();
} else { 
    mHorizontalListViewUsersInChat.setAdapter(usersInChatAdapter);
}
```

Inside the adapter there is an `ImageView` that loads the image with `Picasso`, but when the `adapter` is notified, the new `URL` is not loaded inside the `ImageView`, somebody could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: still with horizontal listview? use recyclerview instead

Comment: Is it possible to make horizontal recyclerview?

Comment: see this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview

Comment: I've implemented the recyclerview but how do I redraw the view?

Comment: I already got it. The problem wasn't the horizontal listview, but yes that I didn't refresh the item changed. My bad. Thanks