# Highlighting for Horizontal Listview Item background on click

Tags: android, horizontallistview

When I click on any Horizontal Listview item , at a time three alternative items get highlighted and it wont unselect. Same Xml file which I applied to Horizontal Listview for highlighting background is worked perfectly for Gridview items. But I don't understand what goes wrong about Horizontal Listview. 
Here is my code.

XML file in drawable.
   Highlight_listview.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/listview_backgroung_color" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/orange" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard" />
</selector>
```

Above code works perfectly for gridview.

xml file where HorizontalListview has mentioned.
  Search_coupon.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="98dp">

        <shoanddonate.citytit.in.shopanddonate.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLaout>
```

xml file from where data for list has fetched. row_cat.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/Highlight_listview">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp">

        <!--Image fetched from network-->
        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/cat_icon"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/CategoryColor"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cat_icon"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to add `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` property to your `HorizontalListView`.

Comment: I add android:choiceMode="singleChoice" to HorizontalListView  but it does not work , still  three items get selected.

Comment: This can be related to the implementation of the third party library that you are using. If you need horizontal list, you don't need third-party libs. Use horizontally oriented `RecyclerView` instead as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460399/2463035