# Android show thousand images in horizontalscrollview from dir

Tags: android, pagination, horizontalscrollview

This is my code to explain how to set horizontal scroll view.

```
 File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

 File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     if(files[i].getName().contains(".png"))
            myGallery.addView(insertPhoto(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad idea. `HorizontalScrollView` is not an `AdapterView`, meaning all your images will be stored in memory, meaning your app will be sluggish and slow, if not crash with `OutOfMemoryException`.

Better use [TwoWayView](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/) for this.