# Horizontally scrolling layout list

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Many apps have a side scrolling list of views: take the new Twitter highlights feature or even the introduction activity of pretty much every app out there.

The main behaviour I'm looking for is a list of views which contain a mixture of text and images, this list of view scroll horizontally instead of vertically & the views 'lock' so they are fully in view no partially.

Is there a built-in view that I'm unaware of (considering I have only been doing this for a few months now I wouldn't be surprised) or something else entirely

Optional request: along side it how would I support pagination style naviagtion

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a built-in view that I'm unaware of or something else entirely** ?

Yes

You can use RecyclerView to show Horizontally Scrolling List . You can visit [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-tutorial/) link to implement RecyclerView .

And to add **HORIZONTAL** scrolling functionality use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview) link .