# How to show a swipeable horizontal list view in android?

Tags: java, android

I have an xml file for a custom list item which contains two text fields and an image in a box. How can I show such listview which can be scrollable horizontally showing one list item after each horizontal swipe?

Comment: Have you tried [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)?

Answer (score 1):

> How to show a swipeable horizontal list view in android?

A `RecyclerView` with `LinearLayoutManager` with `HORIZONTAL` orientation.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Source: [How to build a Horizontal ListView with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview)

**Update:**

> showing one list item after each horizontal swipe?

For this you need a `ViewPager`.