# Horizontal list view in Android?

Tags: android, listview, uicollectionview, grid-layout, tablelayout

Looking for a horizontal list view GUI componnet in Android similar to `UICollectionView` in iOS. I trid `ListView` but was not able to set up to scroll it horizontally.

I need only one line, so no grid like multi line 'table'. I know about `TableLayout` and `GridLayout`. Which one is more proper for my purpose?

Looking for not a 3rd party solution but a standard Android one without loading in and library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a Horizontal ListView with RecyclerView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview)

Comment: The GridView with only one row could help you. TableLayout is not attached to an adapter and didn't recycle views the way recycler View does

Comment: @AlexandreMartin so it is more or less like in iOS, because `UICollectionView` is also a grid-like approach

Comment: To be honest, I do not know anything about iOS dev :(

Comment: use the RecyclerView as shown on the question linked by Gennadi

Comment: @AlexandreMartin I tried `GridView` but can not set column number, or if I set it to a heigher number, then cell content will be reduced. Seems horizontal scroll not possible with `GridView`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the RecyclerLayout, which allows you to specify your own LayoutManager (then you can specify a horizontal one, or a vertical one, or a grid one, or...)

Here is a good SO with a simple example: [How to build a Horizontal ListView with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview)

Comment: Didn't see this answer was a comment in original question

Answer (score 0):

You can use RecycleView and add horizontal layoutmanager

```
RecyclerView listView= (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.hlistview);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        listView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

and in xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/hlistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="30dp"/>
```