# In gridview how to show only one row visible at a time

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-gridview

I am a newbie in android. The grid view of my application has ,any rows and 1 columns. 
I want this to fill the screen ,irrespective of the screen size of the device. My need is i want to show just one row at a time in the user screen.

There are multiple items but only one item(row) should be visible and the next item should only be visible while scrolling.

now follows a code block:
  My Xml Code
  userviewmain_packages.xml

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlklj"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  >  
<GridView 
android:id="@+id/gridview5"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"


  android:numColumns="1"

  android:verticalSpacing="0dp"

   android:scrollbars="none"
   android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout> 



userviewmain_packages_row.xml       

   //  This is the design part(layout) of gridview

     <LinearLayout              
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:linksClickable="true"
 android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
 android:autoLink="web"
 android:gravity="center"

   > 

 //view where weight is added

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linsa2"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/gradient"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:gravity="center" 

     >

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"  

    android:singleLine="true"
     />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/hpid"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/hpiddd"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />


 </LinearLayout>



    //view where weight is added

  <LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/lima"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
  android:linksClickable="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient10"
     android:autoLink="web"


      >


       <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
      android:linksClickable="true"

      android:autoLink="web"
     android:gravity="center"
    >


    <LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="30dp" 
   android:layout_height="30dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
   android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:clickable="true"

   />

  </LinearLayout>



 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#000"  
     android:singleLine="true"

   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
   android:gravity="center"

    />

  <View
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="0.5dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
         android:background="#a8a8a8" />


 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/evdate"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
   android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="16dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:textColor="#000"  
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
   android:gravity="center"
      />


    <View
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="0.5dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
          android:background="#a8a8a8" />

      <TextView
     android:id="@+id/evtime"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="16dp"
     android:textColor="#000"  
    android:singleLine="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
   android:gravity="center"/>

       <View
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="0.5dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
         android:background="#a8a8a8" />


         <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="60dp" 
        android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sub"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/submit"
      />

   </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>   




  </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout
```

Comment: You should be using horizontal recycler view. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28460399/964411)

Comment: cannot it be done using gridview itself... i am doing this in jellybean version

Comment: Never tried with grid view though, but `RecyclerView` will do.