# Android Design Layout ListItem RecyclerView Horizontal

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am using the tools:listitem attribute to show my views in the design layout with a recyclerview.  Problem is, they always show up in a vertical list.  Is there a way to have the Design Layout Editor display them horizontally?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_checked"/>
```

[image]

I want the above image, displayed horizontally.  IN THE DESIGN VIEW.  NOT in the application itself, I know how to do that.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview ?

Comment: Shaishav no it doesn't, this question is not about creating a horizontal recyclerview it is about displaying it in the Design View of Android Studio.

Answer (score 29):

Complete example that works:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/view_item" />
```

PS: *you can replace `androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager` by `android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager` if you don't use **AndroidX**.*

Answer (score 1):

For androidx version or this days after api 28 you should set this attribute

```
    tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

Answer (score 0):

apply these attributes for recyclerview:

```
 tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Example:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvPokemonTeamPokemon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_pokemon_image"
        tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:itemCount="6" />
```