# ListView FullScreen-Item Scroll Horizontal

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am using a ListView populated from MySQL database, the number of listview items are determined by the rows returned from the database (changes when records are updated).

- I do not want to use Fragments
- Each ListView item has clickable buttons (the listView item itself will not be clickable, only the buttons on them will be)

I thought it would be something as simple as defining a horizontal orientation for the listview but it's not the case:

```
   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >
    </ListView>
```

This is what I would like to achieve:
[image]

Comment: You should take a look at the `RecyclerView`. Which is the new way to organize list items. Plus, it's easy to show it horizontally. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview

Answer (score 2):

In this case Either you can Use [HorizontalScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) or [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to achieve expected output.

Edited

As [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4640003/thomas-roulin) Suggested. You can Use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) also

Comment: Its better to use RecyclerView than ViewPager or HorizontalScrollView in his scenario!

Comment: Yes @LalitPoptani I was Editing my question while I got you comment. Thanks.

Comment: You were editing your question or your answer? ;) :P

Comment: The reason behind suggesting ViewPager is 
1.OP wants Some Button inside his ItemView.
2.Single Item of list looks like FullScreen UI.
So...

Comment: Oh! My Answer. :) I don't have any fake SO Profile :P ;)

Comment: Yes, but as he is using ListView already, which is fast scrolling that ViewPager, so in that case RecyclerView suits best!