# Breakdown of this interface

Tags: android

I'm trying to do an app with these elements where you scroll horizontally and new items appear and you have different categories. So far I have the tablayout part done, but I don't know where to go from here can anybody help me please?

It would be something like this

https://thetechportal.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Screenshot_2016-11-18-09-36-49-381_com.airbnb.android.jpg

or something like the top part of this

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/EepbDTFuF8M6gZ5H9SXLY9NYi1Yodmvm6RPp5JWMaRXb_yK6zJyaUBa6xaI0XiLHLw=h310

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it

[image]

[Android Bottom Bar https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html)

[Horizontal RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview)

If you have trouble understanding, get yourself familiar with basic designs first.
This link might help you: 
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-login-and-registration-screen-design/

I know it's very old article, but it shows how to break down UI elements

Comment: Thank you!, I curently have a tab layout as a bottom bar...is there a difference between one and the other?