# How to create an UI with multiple recycler views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm trying to achieve the UI shown in the image. There are several rows with a title and a horizontal RecyclerView below. I could implement it using a lot of TextView/Recyclerviews but I think it will be inefficient and hard to control.

Is there a better way?

[image]

Comment: You should use `RecyclerView` component with horiontal layout.

Comment: Could you explain how I achieve this using one recyclerview with horizontal layout?

Comment: I do not think there is anything to explain . Just search for `RecyclerView` tutorial .`RecyclerView` works both horizontally and vertically . Use `SnapHelper` to get snap effect on first item .

Comment: @alexpfx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview

Comment: I don't think a another way .While all lists are independent from each other . `RecyclerView` is the ultimate solution AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution using this [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) that allows a unique RecyclerView to be split into several sections:

[image]