# Infinite Scrolling Horizontal ScrollView

Tags: java, android

I'm developing my first app for a school project. I've never got java lessons so I am learning all the fundamentals of creating an android app all by myself. Currently, my app is integrated with Firebase Realtime database, and I have in my Home_Fragment, a HorizontalScrollView with a FrameLayout inside it and, inside that FrameLayout I have three ImageViews. It is something like this: [Click here to see it, please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgXcV.png). I hope you can understand what I did. Those ImageViews hold some images that are stored in my Firebase Realtime database. This is my XML starting of that HorizontalScrollView:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrlVPrincipal2"
    android:layout_width="545dp"
    android:layout_height="414dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtHomeDesc"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.42"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="1000dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="1066dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgCard1"
                android:layout_width="259dp"
                android:layout_height="390dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.801" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgCard3"
                android:layout_width="259dp"
                android:layout_height="390dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="221dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.801" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtPaisNome"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgCard2"
                android:layout_width="259dp"
                android:layout_height="390dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginStart="298dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.801" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

and this is the code I use to get the images from the Database (and the respective name of the country):

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference countriesRef = mDatabase.child("paises");
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> nomePaisList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String url = ds.child("Imagem").getValue(String.class);
                String nomePais = ds.child("Nome").getValue(String.class);
                urlList.add(url);
                nomePaisList.add(nomePais);
            }

            int urlCount = urlList.size();
            int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(urlCount);
            List<String> randomUrlList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> randomNomePaisList = new ArrayList<>();
           for (int i=0; i<=Constants.TOTAL_PAISES; i++) {
                randomUrlList.add(urlList.get(randomNumber));
                randomNomePaisList.add(nomePaisList.get(randomNumber));
                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(randomUrlList.get(i)).into(imgCard1); // Inserir na ImageView a imagem do respetivo país
                txtPaisNome.setText(randomNomePaisList.get(i)); // Inserir na TextView o nome do respetivo país
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    countriesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

With all that said, what I wanted to ask is:
How can I make the scroll of those ImageViews infinite? Everytime the user swipes, the ImageView that isn't showing gets a new image and that gives the effect of ImageViews?

Comment: You need to put the data in a `RecyclerView` and set its orientation to horizontal. It's explained in more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview#28460399

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using recycle view rather than scroll view.

Use recycle view horizontally and add scroll listeners.

Then load the image from the server and display it.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    totalItemCount = llm.getItemCount();
    lastVisibleItem = llm.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
        isLoading = true;
        myList.add(new myObject(TYPE_BOTTOM_LOADING));
        recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(myList.size() - 1);
            }
        });
        startIndex += INDEX_INTERVAL;
        endIndex += INDEX_INTERVAL;
        getMyList(startIndex, endIndex);
    }
}});
```

Please refer to here :)
http://www.devexchanges.info/2017/02/android-recyclerview-dynamically-load.html

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer me! In that site, it says that I need to use CardView. Is that really necessary?

Comment: Use cardView or recycleView. Both are your best answers. Use what you can do well. @AndréSilva

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually thinking that what you are trying to do is impossible. But if you are ready to try something new, I suggest you `RecyclerView` and when last element in `RecyclerView` is reached, retrieve data from database, add into `RecyclerView`'s data list.

Comment: Impossible? Isn't it used, for example, in facebook, when you scroll down and an amount of information loads on your timeline?

Comment: you thought they are using `HorizontalScrollView`?

Comment: No, I don't understand even the difference between all the views that exist xd. As I told you, I am noobie in this language ahah

Comment: if you want to use `CardView`, you can simply use `CardView` to display element inner `RecyclerView`, it's okay.

Comment: It's the first tutorial in Flutter, which compiles to Java when building the Android APK so it has to be possible.