# How do I make this kind of design in Android Studio using Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to create [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyg08.png) kind of design using `RecyclerView` I am trying this to achieve the result using this code. My problem is I want the middle circle is bigger and if it goes right or left its size will become smaller. I tried this code but it is not enough

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserListAdapter.UserViewHolder holder, final int position) {

 holder.rlImgsize.getLayoutParams().height = holder.rlImgsize.getHeight() * 2;
 holder.rlImgsize.getLayoutParams().width = holder.rlImgsize.getWidth() * 2

}
```

This is I want to get the result but I can't find any to solve this problem. Please help?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview

Comment: yes Sir i saw that before but that is not the solution of my problem