# Android UI - What Layout to be used to draw many ImageView horizontally

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, uiimageview

i have some images, let's say 4 to 10 images.

i want them to draw horizontally and dynamically resize if more image added.

for example in below script, i have 4 images. but the fourth image not drawed (only 3 images visible) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ball_1"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ball_1a"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ball_1b"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ball_1c"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

design screenshot :

[image]

any idea to solve ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can use recleriew with the layoutmanager of HORIZONTAL.. It will add the view dynamically as per the size of your object.Thanks.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/code-an-image-gallery-android-app-with-glide--cms-28207 will help to u

Comment: @Lucefer what API minimum can use glide ?

Comment: @anunixercoder Minimum Android SDK: Glide v4 requires a minimum API level of 14. follow this https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use horizontal `RecyclerView`

Here is how to setup:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Check this example: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45953855/4224024)

Comment: How about if i'm using API below 20 ? it seems `LinearLayoutManager` just added in API 22