# I'd like make scrollable cards inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So, basically, I have a fragment and in this fragment, I'd like to implement a ViewPager that allows the user to scroll between cards, (btw I ask you what I should use to make these), but I know that the ViewPager it can be used only inside activities, so how could I manage to do that?

I've added the ViewPager in the XML file of the fragment, but then I got stuck when it comes to adding the ViewPager object in the java code and to associate it with the cards.

Answer (score 0):

Since using a `ViewPager` inside a fragment is a headache. Maybe you can try using a RecyclerView with a horizontal orientation.
Something like this:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

more on this here: [How to build a Horizontal ListView with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview)

Comment: Gives me an error when I set the context as "this" because I'm inside of a fragment and not of activity.

Comment: use `getContext()` instead of this