# How to get two cardview items in a single row?

Tags: android

```
Cardview.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_cardview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have implemented cardview using the Recyclerview Adapter. I want to get two cards in a row. I tried Gridview but it didn't work. What is the other way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a Horizontal ListView with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview)

Answer (score 2):

You can use GridLayoutManager in Adapter class.
use it in adapter constracter.Second parameter is Number of columns.

```
mGridLayoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(context,2);
```

later set Layoutmanager in adapter class.You can use this code.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(@NonNull final RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `LinearLayoutManager` and orientation is as `HORIZONTAL` for example

```
LinearLayoutManager llManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
llManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llManager);
```