# View inside scrollview doesn't scroll while scrolling recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

i have a recycler view which contains a lot of posts. while i scroll the recyclerview my frame layout doesn't scroll. it is fixed like a navigation bar.
I want it to scroll as if it was part of the recyclerview.
Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".HomePageFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/status_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

i tried using nestedScrollView but it adds extra empty posts. I dont know why.

[image]

My frameLayout is the status part. which is another recyclerview itself.while scrolling the posts the statuspart doesn't scroll.

Comment: any screenshots would be helpful

Comment: what you mean by status part? the dead pool circles?

Comment: yes those deadpol circles. they are on top of the post

Comment: Do you want them to scroll vertically with posts?

Comment: yes thats the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for status part to scroll with posts in the recyclerview, status part should also be an item in the recyclerview, so you need `recyclerview with multiple view types` for this case. [Plase read: How to create recyclerview with multiple view types.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Just remove the `Framelayout` it's not necessary, when using recyclerviews with multiple view types.

**Minor improvements**

Remove the outer `scrollview` its unnecessary, since recyclerview by default is scrollable.

**Edit**:

In order for status part to be scrollable horizontally, status part item layout should contain a `recyclerview` where [LinearLayoutManager orientation set to horizontal.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460399/7356355) Remember to implement the adapter class for the horizontal recyclerview also.

For you to get started with recyclerview with multiple view types, you may look at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVJpWSalzbo).

---

You may also use library like [Epoxy](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy) in this case.

Comment: The status part is another recyclerview which scrolls horizontally. while the post part scrolls vertically. is it possible to do using what you suggest?

Comment: yes its possible, updated the answer. please make sure to upvote and accept the answer if it satisfy you. You may look at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVJpWSalzbo)