# Android RecycleViewer with multiple horizontal lists

Tags: android, list

I have been trying to implement horizontal lists inside a RecycleView and have a working single horizontal list thenks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45953855, can anyone advise on the required modifications to have multiple horizontal lists based on the provided example?

Cheers

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take 1 Recyclerview Vertical.
2. Now inside the cell of the recyclerview place second recyclerview Horizontal.
3. Now set every recyclerview(vertical) items(cells) with adapter and it will work fine with vertical and horizontal data.

if you find any query, let me know i would help you.

Comment: Can you point me at any implementations of this in Java. Cheers