# Have to manage Recyclerview with two rows - orientation horizontal

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have to display recyclerview for some images. Design should be as below :

Initially, On Screen it should be look like this :

```
Image 1 Image 3 
Image 2 Image 4
```

Now, When User Scrolls it horizontally,

```
Image 1 Image 3 Image 5 Image 7
Image 2 Image 4 Image 6 Image 8
```

Condition is to display with maximum of Two rows. User can scroll list of images horizontally.

To Achieve this, What can I use ?

If we use RecyclerView then How can this be possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this post, should be helpful for you [How to build a Horizontal ListView with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL); 
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Comment: This is supperb @S-Sh

Comment: @how to pass column for staggered ?

Comment: @JaiminModi If orientation is vertical, spanCount is number of columns. If orientation is horizontal, spanCount is number of rows.