# What widget/container should I use?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, gridview

My problem is this, I need a 2d array of buttons. There are 164 buttons in total separated in 19 rows. I tried with gridview but I couldn't make it work because grid view only goes vertical, I need it to go horizontal because the buttons are a constant size so a horizontal scroll would be really helpful. If there's a way to make gridview also go horizontal I'd be great but as long as it works, I don't mind using something else altogether. So, if you can, any code or links are much appreciated.

Comment: Use `RecyclerView` with a horizontal `LayoutManager`. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily by using a RecyclerView  with a horizontal LayoutManager