# Scrolling Card List item by item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm going to create a card list like Google Play app that always show 3 items completely and one or two item part that tell us that the list has more items.

This is easy by `RecyclerView` that use `LinearLayoutManager` in `HORIZONTAL` mode. That explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460399/3257579).

But the problem is item by item scrolling like Google Play app that doesn't stop in any place and if you stop scrolling in middle of an item it moves to begin of that.

And it shows  exactly 3 item in the main box not 2 and a half or 3 and a few.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Library just for that case named GravitySnapHelper: https://github.com/rubensousa/GravitySnapHelper

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewpager for this.