# Resize LinearLayout or RelativeLayout after resizing ImageView inside it

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to put an ImageView inside a RelativeLayout. Just like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I know that this image will be resized in some devices because it would be too big for the device's screen. The remaining resized layout is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k09XH.jpg), notice the gray area around the image, wich is the original RelativeLayout BEFORE resizing, I think!

How can I remove that remaining space? Thanks!

Comment: You can resize your pic using Picasso library

Comment: I want to resize the container of the ImageView, not the image itself! please, watch the image I uploaded

Comment: Here is a same problem, see if it works for you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425151/change-relative-layout-width-and-height-dynamically

Comment: None of those comments worked for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is not working, the image now uccupes all the space!