# Scaling a bitmap to height and width of sceen

Tags: android

I have a bitmap image that is larger than then screen size. I want to scale the image in pixels down to the screen size ? How can i do this ? I want to scale it maintaining aspect ratio not just resize it ?

Kind Regards

Comment: did u tried scaletype:fitxy? property

Comment: No i want to scale it programetically

Comment: yup that can be appyied programtically also

Answer (score 0):

use this function with argument as screenWidth and screenHeight

```
public Bitmap scaleCenterCrop(Bitmap source, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
int sourceWidth = source.getWidth();
int sourceHeight = source.getHeight();

// Compute the scaling factors to fit the new height and width, respectively.
// To cover the final image, the final scaling will be the bigger 
// of these two.
float xScale = (float) newWidth / sourceWidth;
float yScale = (float) newHeight / sourceHeight;
float scale = Math.max(xScale, yScale);

// Now get the size of the source bitmap when scaled
float scaledWidth = scale * sourceWidth;
float scaledHeight = scale * sourceHeight;

// Let's find out the upper left coordinates if the scaled bitmap
// should be centered in the new size give by the parameters
float left = (newWidth - scaledWidth) / 2;
float top = (newHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;

// The target rectangle for the new, scaled version of the source bitmap will now
// be
RectF targetRect = new RectF(left, top, left + scaledWidth, top + scaledHeight);

// Finally, we create a new bitmap of the specified size and draw our new,
// scaled bitmap onto it.
Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, source.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest);
canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, targetRect, null);

return dest;
}
```

for how to get screen width and height see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height)

Comment: how do i get the screen width and screen height ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the screen size and pass those parameters into the following function :

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalimage, width, height, true);
```

Comment: this will give outOfMemoryError while we have high resolution image.

Comment: try to compress the image, then.

Comment: where u fetch the image from?