# Custom Actionbar imageview needs to fit

Tags: android, android-actionbar, imageview, banner

I have a very simple question.

I have been asked by my company to make the actionbar just a simple imageview. So no icon, no title and no buttons at all. I've created a custom actionbar, and the imageview is up there just fine. I have attached a link to an image of my layout, and the emulator on the right. They want the imageview to be like it is in the layout. But in the emulator it comes up small.

My question is simply: is there a way I can make the imageview fit like it is in the layout there, and of course have it fit for different devices too - or, must the graphic designer simply create a banner that fits the size of an actionbar. If so, I looked at android's iconography and saw the height should be 48dp. but what about the width? And won't different devices have different width? Or will i be able to make sure it is stretched across the whole width of the screen. I've tried match parent in my xml but of course it won't do anything now because it doesn't want to stretch the height of the actionbar.

Thanks alot

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1tek8ptar3j76d4/Screenshot%202015-02-27%2009.55.30.png?dl=0

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342463/stretch-image-to-fit, might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your graphic designer make you a 9 patch png that will expand in the middle while keeping its proportions then simply add this line of code:
`getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_nine_patch_png));`

More on nine patch images here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: thanks very much. I will get her to do that. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trick!

```
yourImageView.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
```

Happy coding! ;D

Comment: hi, thank you for your comment. unfortunately this did not have any effect. thank you :)