# How can I get wrap_content or match_parent layout width and height in android?

Tags: android, height, width

I want to get my layout or view (not screen size) width an height in some android devices, so how can i do this? For example:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:paddingRight="8dp"
     android:paddingLeft="8dp"
     android:id="@+id/layout_scrol_left"/>
```

I have this layout and i want to get layout width and height size (in dip) in runtime, how can i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Screen width and height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height)

Comment: my question is different , i want to get my view or layout size in running time , not screen size

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you need to take your layout.

```
LinearLayout ll_left = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_scrol_left);
```

Now if ll_left is not yet drawn both ll_left.getHeight() and ll_left.getWidth() will return 0.

So you have to get them after your view is drawn:

```
ll_left.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
       int height = ll_left.getHeight();
       int weight = ll_left.getWidth();
    }
});
```

Comment: No problem. Remember to mark the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use something like

```
    LinearLayout myView =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_scrol_left);
```

and you can use the methodes below after the UI thread has been sized and laid

```
    myview.getHeight();
    myview.getWidth();
```

hope this helps .

if you problems using the method above take a look at [getWidth() and getHeight() of View returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0)

Comment: The code above should do the trick, though, don't call it too early (onCreate for example) as the UI has to be sized and laid first. 
Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0 for further info

Comment: it dosent work . myview.getHeight and myview.getWidth() =0

Comment: i think you are calling it too early , you should Use it after UI thread has sized and laid . look at the link given by @fbwnd above