# Is it possible to manipulate every pixel using any element in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

Actually this idea came to my mind and i want to fill the image on android screen with almost all the possible colors there could be. So i somehow want to create an image view (if possible) and randomly set color code for each pixel or tiny cubes and fill the image view with this manner. So could someone tell me if it is possible then how could i achieve it. 
I searched a lot for something useful but couldn't find it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `I searched a lot`. No, you did not.

Comment: If it took someone who's never done what youre describing 4 minutes on google/ android docs to find an answer, no you havent "searched a lot"

Comment: I did it guys. Maybe i was just searching with wrong query. Believe me.

Comment:  why would i ask a question if i did not..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Bitmap.

Make an array of the colors you want that has the size equal to the size of the bitmap

Use `createBitmap(int[] colors, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)` and pass the above mentioned array as the first parameter

Read more about [createBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) here

Edit: Since you want the image to cover the whole screen, the size should be equivalent to the screen size in pixels. You can learn how to get screen size [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height)

Comment: How would i know how many values i should pass. And how would i know when the size of the bitmap ends. Will it handle all that automatically...?

Comment: Did you read the explanation of the method? I've linked it to my answer

Comment: Ohh sorry. I am new to SO so i am not familiar with the color scheme.

Comment: It isn't opening. Chrome gives error ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED   plz check the if the  link address is correct.

Comment: I fixed the link @Ashu

Comment: Thanx for the help @howdoidothis.. Damn it was such an easy thing. I am embarrassed now. I can't handle more downvotes so i guess i might delete this que. But for your help i will upvote your answer on some other que from your profile. Thanx again.

Comment: Even if you didn't search the right things. Show the community you tried at least some thing. Add what you think might work/ what you have tried into your question. And while trying to do that, you might actually find the solution yourself

Comment: umm... if you say so.