# Relative Screen size in android

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

I have a grid view and i want 10 buttons in a row. What should be the size of the buttons to fit exactly 10 buttons in width. If i take in **mm** or ***in*** it would work for only one type of screen. Any tips on how to use ***dp*** or ***dip*** is appreciable .

Comment: you should dynamically calculate it as screen size / 10, and do it before populating the GridView. Also you can try to set the `android:numColumns="2"` attribute of the GridView, and set the views width to `match_parent`

Comment: Thanks! but how can i get the value of Screen size dynamically?

Comment: i want the size to be static...like using "dp"

Comment: How about using a horizontal linearLayout? You can set its weightSum attribute to 10, and then set a weight of 1 on each button. They will all have the same size, and will fit on a row.

Comment: there is no way for it to be *static* on *dynamical* size of the screen (for different devices). dp is not what you think, it is dynamical too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each screen having different sizes you would need to base it on the size of the screen loading the app. I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height) may help you there.

In addition, to better understand `dp` or Density-independent pixels, you may want to look [here](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/units-measurements.html#units-measurements-pixel-density) for the equation of a `dp` and using them in a layout of an application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that providing basically only 2 links in the answer is a bad answer.