# Trying to get screen size in onDraw method

Tags: android

in the MainActivity class the following code works fine to get screen size

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

I wanted to get the width and height in my `onDraw` method so if the user rotates the device the method would see the new values

so I copied the code into my `onDraw` method.

I get a error saying:

> getWindowManager() is undefined

I'm assuming this because the onDraw method is in a different class si it does not have that method.

Is there a way to get the screen size in the onDraw method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Screen width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height)

Comment: What class's `onDraw()` are you putting this into? That makes a difference. In general you should probably override `onMeasure()` if you are making a custom view?

Comment: where does onDraw() method belong to? fragment or activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've guessed, `getWindowManager()` is a method of `Activity`, not `View`, so you cannot call it from your `onDraw()` implementation.

However, there are other ways to get a `WindowManager` instance. Below code will work, though in general allocating objects inside `onDraw()` is not recommended.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    manager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
}
```