# Updating Glide image into ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, image-resizing, android-glide

I have two screens of the app.One is edit screen and another is modify screen.I am loading the images into list using Glide in edit screen with 100*100 size successfully using below code.

```
public static void loadEditImage(ImageView view, String imageUrl){
        Glide.with(view.getContext())
                .load(imageUrl)
                .transform(new CircleTransform(mContext))
//                .placeholder(R.drawable.car_logo_bg)
                .override(600, 200)

                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(view);
    }
```

Same image i am trying to display in modify screen with 140*140 size using same image URL. But the image its displaying the size with 100*100 instead of 140*140. Below glide code is using for this screen.

```
public static void loadModifyImage(ImageView view, String modifyImageUrl){
        Glide.with(view.getContext())
                .load(modifyImageUrl)
                .asBitmap()
                .transform(new CircleTransform(mContext))
//                .placeholder(R.drawable.car_logo_bg)
                .override(600, 200)

//                .centerCrop()
//                .fitCenter()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                .into(view);
    }
```

Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong and help me to display the image with the size of 140*140.

Comment: you have use centerCrop() ??

Comment: yes if i use that image is displaying center of the ImageView. But i want to display that in fullsize.

Comment: Why you   .override(600, 200) ?

Comment: Check: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling

Comment: for resizing the image i am using override(600,200).

Comment: I followed the same tutorial for resizing but no luck..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
imageview.setLayoutParams(140, 140);
```

Comment: I have given wrap_content to both.Because i am loading different size images from network.So if i put fixed size,small images lossing the quality and big images overriding on top of imageview.

Comment: You can get the screen width https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height and then according to that you can set fixed size.

Comment: I don't want to load image as per the screen resolution.The ImageView size is fixed like 140*140.Need to load image into it using glide

Comment: Hey, why to use override(600, 200)?  Try override(100, 100) for edit screen and (140, 140) for modify screen.