# What is correct way to capture screen size in android

Tags: android

Searching on google i found various way get the screen size, here's what i got.

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    Log.i(TAG, "first way width = "+size.x);
    Log.i(TAG, "first way height = "+size.y);

    int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    Log.i(TAG, "second way width = "+width);
    Log.i(TAG, "second way height = "+height);

    int height2 = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    int width2 = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    Log.i(TAG, "third way width = "+width2);
    Log.i(TAG, "third way height = "+height2);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height3 = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width3 = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    Log.i(TAG, "fourth way width = "+width3);
    Log.i(TAG, "fourth way height = "+height3);
```

On logging all are giving the same result. I was wondering if there any difference between all these methods or any specific use cases?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height

Comment: I would stick to `Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics` because it doesn't rely on context like the others do

Answer (score 1):

Another way is this :

```
public static DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;

displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
```

for the width of the screen :

```
float screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

for the height of the screen :

```
float screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel use it, this is the code to check screen height and width:

```
/**
     * Return the width of screen, in pixel.
     *
     * @return the width of screen, in pixel
     */
    public static int getScreenWidth() {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) Utils.getApp().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        if (wm == null) {
            return Utils.getApp().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        }
        Point point = new Point();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            wm.getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(point);
        } else {
            wm.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
        }
        return point.x;
    }

    /**
     * Return the height of screen, in pixel.
     *
     * @return the height of screen, in pixel
     */
    public static int getScreenHeight() {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) Utils.getApp().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        if (wm == null) {
            return Utils.getApp().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        }
        Point point = new Point();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            wm.getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(point);
        } else {
            wm.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
        }
        return point.y;
    }
```

picked from this [helper library](https://github.com/Blankj/AndroidUtilCode/blob/master/utilcode/src/main/java/com/blankj/utilcode/util/ScreenUtils.java#L41) by BlankJ