# How can i set the height and width of drawable.setBounds method to display the image properly in different devices perfectly in textview

Tags: java, android

I have an app in which HTML pages come through the API which contains images and text. I am able to display the text and parse the images as well in a text view. But the Image height and width are not perfect. I am using `drawable.setBounds()` method to set the height and width of the image, but if I set it to static suppose `drawable.setBounds(0, 0,1020,600)`, the images come different in different screen sizes. I want to scale the images according to different screen sizes. How can I do that? Below is my code of ImageParser.

**URLImageParser.java**

```
 public class URLImageParser implements Html.ImageGetter {
            Context c;
            TextView container;


            /***
             * Construct the URLImageParser which will execute AsyncTask and refresh the container
             * @param t
             * @param c
             */
            public URLImageParser(TextView t, Context c) {
                this.c = c;

                this.container = t;
            }

            public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                URLDrawable urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();

                // get the actual source
                ImageGetterAsyncTask asyncTask =
                        new ImageGetterAsyncTask( urlDrawable);

                asyncTask.execute(source);

                // return reference to URLDrawable where I will change with actual image from
                // the src tag
                return urlDrawable;
            }

            public class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {
                URLDrawable urlDrawable;

                public ImageGetterAsyncTask(URLDrawable d) {
                    this.urlDrawable = d;
                }



                @Override
                protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
                    String source = params[0];

                    try {
                        URL url= new URL(source);
                        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
                        source=uri.toASCIIString();


                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //Toast.makeText(context, source, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Log.d("Resp",source);

                    return fetchDrawable(source);
                }


                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
                    // set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call
                    urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0
                            + result.getIntrinsicHeight());

                    // change the reference of the current drawable to the result
                    // from the HTTP call
                    urlDrawable.drawable = result;

                    // redraw the image by invalidating the container
                    URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();
                    URLImageParser.this.container.setHeight((URLImageParser.this.container.getHeight()
                            + result.getIntrinsicHeight()));


                }

                /***
                 * Get the Drawable from URL
                 * @param urlString
                 * @return
                 */
                public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
                    try {
                        InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
                        Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
                        drawable.setBounds(0, 0,800,600);
                        return drawable;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                private InputStream fetch(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                    return response.getEntity().getContent();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why you need the Image to scale for different sizes? Show in Image view?

Comment: I have to show in text view because in api it comes like this, check sample api, the element "content" https://www.groveus.com/micro/api/index.php/pages/view?id=4

Comment: @SuhriAbhro why are you showing drawable in textView??

Comment: Because I have to. It is the requirement of the app, that HTML pages will be displayed that does not have a website or actual page, but comes from an api, and page design is made in an editor.

Comment: are you using textView as wrapContent?

Comment: If you are using specific height and width of the text View and show the Image in it and height and width will be manageable according to screen size. so its ok for you??

Comment: No matchParent.

Comment: please have look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height) to get height and width of the screen otherWIse there is a second solution much better for you to give a specific height and width to the textView.

Comment: This did the trick. Thank You.

Comment: I add the answer for your easiness I can share one library for you that manages all screens

Comment: Please test that mark my answer if it helps you.

Comment: Yes please. Share the library. This is just a work around. And how can I mark your answer?

Comment: thanks for marking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this library to make things easier for you to manipulate drawable in different screen sizes.

**Here is the** [Library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

You can put the height and width in SDP it will manage itself for all screens

**For example like this**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvImage"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_9sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_18sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your fetch drawable method  :

```
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0
                        + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

Comment: I tried that already. The problem is, if the image height and width is small, suppose 520*300, the is image is displayed too small in text view. What i want is to get the height and width in percent like in HTML or CSS that it scales the image properly. Or is there any way i can check device size and put a condition that if the device size is 4 inches then a portion of code will run else another?