# Got wrong screen size from android instrumentation test

Tags: java, android, android-testing

when I was trying to get physical screen height and screen width by using UiDevice.getDisplayHeight() getDisplayWidth() or other system method. I got height 1439, width 720, but my real screen size is 2244x1080. I've tried put an manifest in androidTest folder with config:

```
<supports-screens
       android:anyDensity="true"
       android:largeScreens="true"
       android:normalScreens="true"
       android:smallScreens="true"
       android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

but it dose not work.

Comment: are you talking about dp or pixels?

Comment: that is pixels, but i'm confusing that event using screencapture method, i alway got a  coner of the screen, not the full screen. somehow the screen size i got in my androidtest app always wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the size in **pixels**, check out this answer:
[Get screen width and height in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height-in-android)