# android LinearLayout to RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I'm making an application for an android and I have problem.
I want change my XML code from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout.
In one line, I want 4 progressbars. I can do it with LinearLayout but RelativeLayout is not.

Effect:
[image]

Code:

```
      <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/lineral"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <ProgressBar
           android:id="@+id/kcal"
           style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="25dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           android:progress="25"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:progressTint="#69f0ae"
           />

       <ProgressBar
           android:id="@+id/protein"
           style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="25dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           android:progress="25"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@id/kcal"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:progressTint="#03A9F4"
           />

       <ProgressBar
           android:id="@+id/fat"
           style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="25dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@id/protein"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:progress="25"
           android:progressTint="#FFEB3B"
           />

       <ProgressBar
           android:id="@+id/carbohydrates"
           style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="25dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fat"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:progress="25"
           android:progressTint="#F44336"
           />
       </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is better to use linear layout only as per your requirement

Comment: if you can do it with linear layout, why you required to change it to relative layout?

Comment: I want add some text below each ProgressBar

Comment: try [constraint layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all progress bar in the same width you have to use Linearlayout

If you are using relative layout, in all ProgressBar you have to set the width

Answer (score 0):

You are using **android:layout_weight=1** to set the weight of the progress bar But That is a property of LinearLayout.LayoutParams, but not of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.

**Alternative Solutions**

1. You can use Horizontally-oriented LinearLayout Manager in the Recycler View, and place each RelativeLayout in each item, of its Adapter. [Check The Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview/28460399#28460399)
2. If your RelativeLayouts are set to a fixed width and height, that is to the size of the screen, that you can get from DisplayMatrics, that will be OK. [Check The Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height-in-android/4744499#4744499)
3. If the contents of your RelativeLayouts are different, then you can use getItemViewType() method. [Check The Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Desired Constraint Layout View
[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/oP"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:progress="25"
    android:progressTint="#69f0ae"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/oP2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Progress 1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/oP"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/oP"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/oP" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/oP2"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:progress="25"
    android:progressTint="#69f0ae"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/oP3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/oP"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toTopOf="parent"/>



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Progress 2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/oP2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/oP2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/oP2" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/oP3"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/oP4"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:progress="25"
    android:progressTint="#69f0ae"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/oP2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toTopOf="parent"/>



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Progress 2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/oP3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/oP3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/oP3" />


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/oP4"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:progress="25"
    android:progressTint="#69f0ae"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/oP3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Progress 4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/oP4"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/oP4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/oP4" />
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, you should have told that thing in the comment too.

Comment: btw in his layout file if you haven't noticed it is linear layout.. not relative layout.

Comment: yes, I know he is using a linear layout. But he wants to replace it with the relative layout. Kindly check the questions

Comment: Okej but I want to each progressbar add text name value of progressbar and I don't know how do it use LinearLayout

Comment: Simple solution: For that, you have to create a new view for each progress bar. [LinearLayout->RelativeLayout[progressbar and text below]]. 
But recommended solution is to use constraint layout.

Comment: Okej but how do it with constraint layout? (progressbars)

Comment: Check the updated answer, I added the constraint view. it's a simple view with progressbar and textview under the umbrella of single view.