# display.getRealMetrics() is deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, deprecated, android-windowmanager

I was using getRealMetrics() method and came to know that it is deprecated

```
val display = this.display
display?.getRealMetrics(outMetrics)
```

anybody know what is the alternative.

Comment: If you use it to get a screen size, please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70087378/1731626. There is maintainable implementation of getting the screen size written in Kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display#getRealMetrics(android.util.DisplayMetrics)) the recommended way is to use `WindowManager#getCurrentWindowMetrics()`:

```
val metrics: WindowMetrics = context.getSystemService(WindowManager::class.java).currentWindowMetrics
```

If you use it to get screen size, please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70087378/1731626).

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
```

For width and height

```
Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels
Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels
```

Comment: How I can use it as a substitute of display.getRealMetrics(displaymetrics)

Comment: I got it thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use WindowMetricsCalculator to get display height and width parameter

```
dependencies {
implementation "androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta02"}


val windowMetrics = WindowMetricsCalculator.getOrCreate().computeCurrentWindowMetrics(activity)
val currentBounds = windowMetrics.bounds

val width = currentBounds.width()
val height = currentBounds.height()
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi i create this function in xamarin.android: (manifest SDK max 31, min 25)

```
public bool IsTablet()
    {
        var displayMetrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        var defaultDisplay = WindowManager.DefaultDisplay;
        double widthPixels = 0;
        double heightPixels = 0;

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.S) //API 31 and more
        {
            var windowMetrics = WindowManager.CurrentWindowMetrics;

            Rect bounds = windowMetrics.Bounds;
            widthPixels = bounds.Width();
            heightPixels = bounds.Height();   
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt == BuildVersionCodes.R) //API 30
        {
            #pragma warning disable
            defaultDisplay.GetRealMetrics(displayMetrics);

            widthPixels = displayMetrics.WidthPixels;
            heightPixels = displayMetrics.HeightPixels;
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.R) //less then 30
        {
            #pragma warning disable
            defaultDisplay.GetMetrics(displayMetrics);

            widthPixels = displayMetrics.WidthPixels;
            heightPixels = displayMetrics.HeightPixels;
        }

        var wInches1 = widthPixels / (double)displayMetrics.DensityDpi;
        var hInches1 = heightPixels / (double)displayMetrics.DensityDpi;

        double inch = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(wInches1, 2) + Math.Pow(hInches1, 2));

        if (cale >= 7.0)
        {
            tablet = true;
        }

        return tablet;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display

> getRealMetrics(DisplayMetrics outMetrics)
>
> This method was deprecated in API level 31. Use
> WindowManager#getCurrentWindowMetrics() to identify the current size
> of the activity window. UI-related work, such as choosing UI layouts,
> should rely upon WindowMetrics#getBounds(). Use
> Configuration#densityDpi to get the current density.