# getRealMetrics(displayMetrics) is Deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, pdf, canvas

```
val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
       context.display?.getRealMetrics(displayMetrics)
       displayMetrics.densityDpi
   } else{
       activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
   }
```

Can someone give me the solution to this question. It is saying that **getRealMetrics(displayMetrics)** and **defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)** is deprecated. I have seen many sol but none of them helped me.

Comment: check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70087457/8644685

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager#getCurrentWindowMetrics()

Comment: Can you please share github link or write code here as I am new to android dev, things are really complicated.