# Using Jetpack WindowManager to calculate screen size on Android

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack

As Display methods are deprecated in Android 12, I am planning to use Jetpack's backward compatible WindowManager library succeeding Display.

However I am not sure whether I face an issue if I directly access the sizes of a screen in Activity like below:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val windowMetrics = WindowMetricsCalculator.getOrCreate()
        .computeCurrentWindowMetrics(this@WindowMetricsActivity)
    val width = windowMetrics.bounds.width()
    val height = windowMetrics.bounds.height()
}
```

Because Google's sample code insists using `onConfigurationChanged` method by using a utility container view like below:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Add a utility view to the container to hook into
    // View.onConfigurationChanged.
    // This is required for all activities, even those that don't
    // handle configuration changes.
    // We also can't use Activity.onConfigurationChanged, since there
    // are situations where that won't be called when the configuration
    // changes.
    // View.onConfigurationChanged is called in those scenarios.
    // https://issuetracker.google.com/202338815
    container.addView(object : View(this) {
        override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration?) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
            logCurrentWindowMetrics("Config.Change")
        }
    })
}
    
@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
private fun logCurrentWindowMetrics(tag: String) {
    val windowMetrics = WindowMetricsCalculator.getOrCreate()
        .computeCurrentWindowMetrics(this@WindowMetricsActivity)
    val width = windowMetrics.bounds.width()
    val height = windowMetrics.bounds.height()
    adapter.append(tag, "width: $width, height: $height")
    runOnUiThread {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

In our project, we directly access the sizes of screens and I am wondering how we migrate to accessing them after `onConfigurationChanged` invokes and emits the size values by using MAD skills.

Any approaches will be appreciated

Comment: Did you see [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/unbundling-the-stable-windowmanager-a5471ff2907)?

Comment: please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70087378/1731626

Comment: The `WindowMetricsCalculator` is a synchronous API. you can just use that where you need to access the current Window size. The `onConfigurationChanged` snippets is just to get notified when the window size changes (as an example when in multi-window mode the user changes the Window size)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method to get a screen size starting from Android 11 (API level 30):

```
fun getScreenSize(context: Context): Size {
     val metrics: WindowMetrics = context.getSystemService(WindowManager::class.java).currentWindowMetrics
     return Size(metrics.bounds.width(), metrics.bounds.height())
}
```

Comment: I prefer using backward compatible AndroidX WindowManager library including `WindowMetricsCalculator`