# How to remove top and bottom black bar from VLCVideoLayout in android

Tags: android

This is my xml .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/secondView"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <org.videolan.libvlc.util.VLCVideoLayout
            android:id="@+id/videoLayout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thirdLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/secondView"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>
```

This is my class :

```
public class WifiActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BroadcastReceiver MyReceiver = null;

    private static final String url = " rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4";

    private LibVLC libVlc;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private VLCVideoLayout videoLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }

        libVlc = new LibVLC(this);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libVlc);
        videoLayout = findViewById(R.id.videoLayout);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mediaPlayer.attachViews(videoLayout, null, false, false);

        Media media = new Media(libVlc, Uri.parse(url));
        media.setHWDecoderEnabled(true, false);
        media.addOption(":network-caching=600");

        mediaPlayer.setMedia(media);
        media.release();
        mediaPlayer.play();

    }
}
```

after running this code I am able to show live streaming using the given URL look like this.

[image]

I am trying to remove the black bar which is showing in the given image I want to keep it full screen please help me how to achieve this I am unable to find any solution for this.

[image]

Comment: you want to make these bars invisible or you want to "stretch"/center video for fitting whole screen?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @snachmsm
 yes I want to remove  or  invisible the top black  bar  so that i can fit video screen in full video  I tried but unable to do

Comment: @snachmsm I have change live video URl  you  use to see video i want to remove black bar top and bottom from video view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting `layout_height="match_parent"` for `VLCVideoLayout`, so currently it behaves properly, according to written code

if you want different height for this view, then you should calculate it and set for `VLCVideoLayout`. here is fun fact: this class will re-set its width and height at runtime (check out [`onAttachedToWindow`](https://github.com/SteinerOk/libvlc-sdk-android/blob/master/libvlc-android/src/main/java/org/videolan/libvlc/util/VLCVideoLayout.java#L51) method), so even when you set some fixed values in XML - these will be overwritten. its made for "some reason" by library authors, so let's don't touch this class, but now we know that `VLCVideoLayout` will always stretch/fit to parent

so now I would create some parent class for this video view only

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/secondView"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/videoFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <org.videolan.libvlc.util.VLCVideoLayout
                android:id="@+id/videoLayout"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            
        </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

now as we know that frame/video will `match_parent` width then we can measure it by [measuring screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height-in-android). if this video would be packed into some more complicated layout, e.g. some small video frame in corner - you should measure size of this area (which oftenly have fixed width/size in such case)

knowing `videoFrame` width you can calculate easily height with just multiplying by ratio of video

```
int scrWidth = getScreenWidth();
FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.videoFrame);
double ratio = 16d/9d;  // 16:9
frameLayout.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(scrWidth / ratio);
```

Comment: OK Thanks let me try with this

Comment: It worked but one small thing I need help with after applying your logic  my screen is coming something like this which i updated screen in question i want keep it half screen in my device same logic i have applied as you suggest .

Comment: sadly I don't understand what do you want to achieve now... thats new question related to splitting screen to half. XML posted in question is wrong, there's no root in it... please ask new question with updated code (full) and maybe some image with desired look. if you want you may post link in here for me, if I would have time I will try to answer

Comment: Thanks for helping me I am trying to increase the height of the video frame  but when I trying to increase when the again black bar comes I want to fit  it whatever area I will give for the video frame