# Detect device orientation when Activity orientation is locked

Tags: android, view, locking, orientation

In my project, I have to lock the orientation of an activity. (I cannot recreate the activity)

I want to display a message when the user change the orientation of the device that say :
"The View is locked in this position ..."

I can easily lock the orientation with this code:

```
if(version >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
    }else{
        int orientation = activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if(orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }else{
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    }
```

With this code the view is locked but I cannot detect when the user change the device orientation.

And if I use this following code:

```
@Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
     //Check if the orientation has change
     if(newConfig.orientation != mOrientation){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message for user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     //Try to lock the view but not working
     newConfig.orientation = mOrientation;

     //Obligatory line that reload the view and cannot be delete
     //(is the biggest prolem of this code)
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   }
```

If someone know a way to lock the view and detect the change of the device orientation it will really help me.

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

It can also be solved with `SensorManager`. Here is a simple demo shows how to keep image orientation correct for locked activity to portrait:

**MainActivity :**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView img;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mOrientation;

    float value_0 = -10000;
    float value_1 = -10000;
    private SensorEventListener mOrientationSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        int orientation = -1;

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            int value ;
            if(value_0 == event.values[0] && value_1==event.values[1]){
                return;
            }
//            Log.d("values:", "values:" + event.values[0]+", "+event.values[1]);
            if (event.values[1] > 0 && event.values[0] == 0) {
                value = Surface.ROTATION_0;//portrait
                if (orientation != value) {
                    updateImageRotation(value);
                    Log.d("orientation", "portrait  + update");
                }
                orientation = value;
                Log.d("orientation", "portrait ");
            }


            if (event.values[1] < 0 && event.values[0] == 0) {
                value = Surface.ROTATION_180;//portrait reverse
                if (orientation != value) {
                    updateImageRotation(value);
                    Log.d("orientation", "portrait reverse + update");
                }
                orientation = value;
                Log.d("orientation", "portrait reverse");
            }

            if (event.values[0] > 0 && event.values[1] == 0) {
                value = Surface.ROTATION_90;//portrait reverse
                if (orientation != value) {
                    updateImageRotation(value);
                    Log.d("orientation", "landscape  + update");
                }
                orientation = value;
                Log.d("orientation", "landscape");
            }

            if (event.values[0] < 0 && event.values[1] == 0) {
                value = Surface.ROTATION_270;//portrait reverse
                if (orientation != value) {
                    updateImageRotation(value);
                    Log.d("orientation", "landscape  + update");
                }
                orientation = value;
                Log.d("orientation", "landscape reverse");
            }

            value_0=event.values[0];
            value_1=event.values[1];
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        // Get sensor manager
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        // Get the default sensor of specified type
        mOrientation = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mOrientation != null) {
            mSensorManager.registerListener(mOrientationSensorListener, mOrientation,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOrientation != null) {
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mOrientationSensorListener);
        }
    }


    private void updateImageRotation(int degree) {

        switch (degree) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                img.setRotation(0);
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                img.setRotation(90);
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                img.setRotation(180);
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                img.setRotation(270);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In manifest. Orientation is locked to `portrait` and sensor is required as feature
**manifest.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="permissionsmngr.com.apipas.rotationmanage"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="permissionsmngr.com.apipas.rotationmanage.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why did you choose SensorEventListener not SensorEventListener2?

Comment: @chinmish nothing special .. just not interested to receive onFlushCompleted

Comment: Hello, how is this working? I mean, I see event.values[0] and event.values[1] changing from positive to negative numbers or vice-versa, but they're never exactly == 0

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `OrientationEventListener` to take **orientation from sensor** *(written in Kotlin)*:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var orientationEventListener: OrientationEventListener? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ...

        orientationEventListener = object : OrientationEventListener(context) {
            override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation: Int) {
                // orientation is in degrees

                // Show "The View is locked in this position ..." message if orientation is between 45° and 315°
                viewModel.showViewIsLocked(orientation in 45..315)
            }
        }       
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        orientationEventListener?.enable()      
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        orientationEventListener?.disable()
        super.onPause()
    }

}
```

Comment: this answer works fine and also it's very simple. it's really underrated!

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for me.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startService( new Intent(this, Receiver.class) );
}
}
```

**BackgroundService.java**

```
public class Receiver extends Service {
    private static final String BCAST_CONFIGCHANGED = "android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED";
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BCAST_CONFIGCHANGED);
        this.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    }

    public BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent myIntent) {
            if ( myIntent.getAction().equals( BCAST_CONFIGCHANGED ) ) {
                if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
                }
                else {
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**Manifestfile.xml**

```
<service android:name=".Receiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: Thank you.But the problem with this solution it's if I lock the view the CONFIGURATION_CHANGED intent it's no more call. (I think when the view is locked changing the orientation of the device don't change the configuration)