# How to detect the device orientation with SensorEventListener?

Tags: imagebutton, screen-orientation, android-sensors, sensormanager, rotateanimation

I would like to detect the device screen orientation by implementing the SensorEventListener, because its current screen orientation is set to portrait by default. I need to do this, because my layout includes some buttons that should rotate independently from their layout and the only way to do this (as long as I know) is by overriding the onConfigurationChanged and adding the corresponding animation to each screen orientation. I don't think an OrientationEventListener would work since the set orientation is fixed to portrait. So how can I retrieve the screen orientation or angle rotations from the sensor itself?

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826227/how-to-determine-device-orientation-from-the-sensors/32837770#32837770.

Comment: That's not what I need. I need to detect the device motion to rotate buttons depending on it. The layout stays portray as it is.

Comment: What do you mean by device motion? If the device is not flat, then you can use the link above to get angle which would tell you what orientation the device screen is in. You can test by not setting the activity to portrait mode and then rotate the screen to see at what angle it will flip to landscape. It may be device dependent.

Comment: That's the problem, the device needs to be set to portrait mode as I am not looking to create different layouts, but to play with the animation of the buttons basing on the sensor without the layout changing orientation. Check VSCO Cam camera activity button rotation when you move the device, and how the layout stays the same.

Comment: I am not asking you to not set your activity to Portrait mode in production. I am just telling you to test without setting your activity to portrait and then rotate the device. When the screen change your activity from Portrait to Lanscape, note the angle return from OrientationEventListener. So at this angle the device flip from Portrait to Lanscape. Now set your activity to portrait and when the onOrientationChanged return this angle rotates your button. Or you can just decides at which angle it would be Landscape for you and rotate it when onOrientationChanged is at this angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An OrientationEventListener will work, even with fixed orientation; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8260007/1382108. It monitors the sensor according to the documentation.
Say you define the following constants:

```
private static final int THRESHOLD = 40;
public static final int PORTRAIT = 0;
public static final int LANDSCAPE = 270;
public static final int REVERSE_PORTRAIT = 180;
public static final int REVERSE_LANDSCAPE = 90;
private int lastRotatedTo = 0;
```

The numbers correspond to what the OrientationEventListener returns, so if you have a natural landscape device (tablet) you have to take that into account, see [How to check device natural (default) orientation on Android (i.e. get landscape for e.g., Motorola Charm or Flipout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553650/how-to-check-device-natural-default-orientation-on-android-i-e-get-landscape).

```
 @Override
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
    int newRotateTo = lastRotatedTo;
    if(orientation >= 360 + PORTRAIT - THRESHOLD && orientation < 360 ||
            orientation >= 0 && orientation <= PORTRAIT + THRESHOLD)
        newRotateTo = 0;
    else if(orientation >= LANDSCAPE - THRESHOLD && orientation <= LANDSCAPE + THRESHOLD)
        newRotateTo = 90;
    else if(orientation >= REVERSE_PORTRAIT - THRESHOLD && orientation <= REVERSE_PORTRAIT + THRESHOLD)
        newRotateTo = 180;
    else if(orientation >= REVERSE_LANDSCAPE - THRESHOLD && orientation <= REVERSE_LANDSCAPE + THRESHOLD)
        newRotateTo = -90;
    if(newRotateTo != lastRotatedTo) {
        rotateButtons(lastRotatedTo, newRotateTo);
        lastRotatedTo = newRotateTo;
    }
}
```

The rotateButtons functions being something like:

```
public void rotateButtons(int from, int to) {

    int buttons[] = {R.id.buttonA, R.id.buttonB};
    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(from, to, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        rotateAnimation.setDuration(200);
        rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        View v = findViewById(buttons[i]);
        if(v != null) {
            v.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
        }
    }
}
```