# Rotate an image only in fragment automatically not activity

Tags: android, image, android-activity, rotation

I want to rotate an image only and not whole activity. So, when I apply

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

The above line of code in a fragment rotates the image but when back to activity, fragment tabs also rotate.
And when I change in manifest for portrait and landscape then whole activity rotated.

How to fix it?

Comment: Do you want to rotate the fragment or do you want to rotate the fragment on device rotation? For rotating the fragment just rotate its view via setRotation

Comment: I want to rotate image on device rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imageView.setRotation(angle)` to change the `rotation` of your `ImageView`.

Comment: I want to rotate image on device rotation.

Comment: It is showing JNI setFloatArrayRegion called pending Exception @Ferdous

Answer (score 0):

Use an [OrientationEventListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html) and rotate the image on orientation changes.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27617038/923441)

Comment: What do you mean