# How to receive onConfigurationChanged events (Android SDK)

Tags: android, layout, onconfigurationchanged

The goal is to fix the screen layout as "landscape" or "portrait" and continue to receive rotation events.
I know about **onConfigurationChanged**(Configuration newConfig) in Activity but it does not work with fixed layouts. How to deal with this?
To explain more clearly I want to implement a behaviour like in Android Camera application - rotate only button images but not reload activity and not change the layout.

EDIT#1:
I mean this method does not work after calling **setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)**

EDIT#2:
Yes, **onConfigurationChanged** was not what I need. Instead **SensorEventListener** interface should be implemented and check for **onSensorChanged** events.
Complete solution, taken from [Get phone orientation but fix screen orientation to portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021890/get-phone-orientation-but-fix-screen-orientation-to-portrait):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
int orientation = -1;
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.values[1] < 6.5 && event.values[1] > -6.5) {
        if (orientation != 1) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LANDSCAPE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
        toast.show(); 
    }
    orientation = 1;
    } else {
        if (orientation != 0) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PORTRAIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
        toast.show(); 
        }
    orientation = 0;
    }
}
```

And this works excellent with this AndroidManifest setting for your activity:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Comment: what do you mean by "fixed layouts"? usually on rotation change you activity gets destroyed and is recreated. the activiy-s onCreate should handle ""landscape" or "portrait"". why do you need to handle onConfigurationChanged ?

Comment: I mean calling setRequestedOrientation() to fix landscape or portraid layout. May be I am wrong with this onConfigurationChanged event and should select another method, but do not know how?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare it in manifest file of your project-

```
    <activity
        android:name="your_activity_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation" >
    </activity>
```

And override method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

in your activity class.

Comment: Again, it does not work with fixed layout.  For example, after calling setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) you never get the next onConfigurationChanged event