# How to get device orientation whilst locking device in portrait

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

In my app I have set preferred orientations of portrait

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
])
```

But I would like to listen for changes in the orientation without changing what is displayed on the screen

> I want to listen for orientation changes even though it is locked

I would like some code equivalent to this

`MediaQuery.of(context).orientation`

However, since I have locked it to portrait it will always say portrait

Answer (score 0):

You can use SensorManager class for this:

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorManager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener() {
        int orientation=-1;;

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.values[1]<6.5 && event.values[1]>-6.5) {
                if (orientation!=1) {
                    Log.d("Sensor", "Landscape");
                }
                orientation=1;
            } else {
                if (orientation!=0) {
                    Log.d("Sensor", "Portrait");
                }
                orientation=0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

There are also other ways you can check in this post: [Get phone orientation but fix screen orientation to portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021890/get-phone-orientation-but-fix-screen-orientation-to-portrait)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this package [native_device_orientation](https://pub.dev/packages/native_device_orientation) it provides accurate orientation and doesn't just look at the devices width.

```
// Gets the devices orientation
NativeDeviceOrientation orientation = await NativeDeviceOrientationCommunicator().orientation(useSensor:true);
```