# What's the difference between Screen Orientation and -Rotation on Android?

Tags: android, screen, screen-orientation

What's the difference between Screen Orientation and -Rotation on Android? The terms are often used interchangeably on the web it seems.

According to [a discussion on the deprecation of Display.getOrientation() for getRotation()](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/HUon8SKCA2Q) the concepts are often misunderstood/confused. No further explanation is provided however.

I suspect it's important to understand the intricacies of Orientation and Rotation on Android devices to correctly display an App even on exotic devices.

Comment: They just can be used interchangeably. But the best one to use is getRotation if you check the documentation of android here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getOrientation()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the link you gave Miss Dianne Hackborn clearly stated;

"getOrientation() has never returned orientation, it returns rotation.  So it is being renamed to getRotation().  This is *much* less confusing.  In fact you were confused -- you thought it returned orientation, when it does not."

To describe more deeply;

- Orientation: is concept for defining landscape, portrait, ...
- Rotation: [Returns the rotation of the screen from its "natural" orientation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29) The natural orientation is important here, because it is landscape on tablets and portrait on smaller devices.

Comment: And this "natural" orientation (implied through the "natural" width and height) is available through getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(), as per http://stackoverflow.com/q/4553650/110597