# getrotation( ) returns different values on Samsung Galaxy p1000 (4.1 Jelly Bean) and Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1 (3.2)

Tags: android, android-imageview, screen-rotation

i'm using the getrotation function to detect the initial rotation of a screen when my activity is created. But when i used to logged out what returns this function, i mentioned that on my P1000, when rotation = 1 or 3, this means my tablet is in landscape. But on my 10.1 tab, when rotation = 0 or 2, this means my tablet is in landscape. This is causing me a problem in the background image usage replacement. This is my code :

```
HomeBackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home_background);
    Display display = ((WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int rotation = display.getRotation();

        if (rotation == 1 || rotation == 3) {
        HomeBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_bg_landscape);
    } else {
        HomeBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_bg_portrait);
    }
```

So whats the solution to detect the initial rotation of a screen using another method? or what is my bug?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for `Display.getRotation()`:

> Returns the rotation of the screen from its "natural" orientation.

The natural orientation of the Galaxy Tab 10.1 is landscape, and I'm assuming for the other device it's portrait.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553650/how-to-check-device-natural-default-orientation-on-android-i-e-get-landscape) might help in determining what the default orientation is

Comment: So whats the solution to detect the initial rotation of the screen when the user launches the app, not the "natural" orientation?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553650/how-to-check-device-natural-default-orientation-on-android-i-e-get-landscape) very useful for me. That what i need! Thank you.