# GetCameraDisplayOrientation returns always 0

Tags: android, android-camera, screen-orientation, android-video-player

I'm trying to record a video in the correct orientation in Android. I've built my Activity, it works correctly, the only thing is that the saved video after being recorded is rotated. The preview of the camera works correctly so I can't understand why. To fix the rotation I use this code (the method I've found on Google Developers):

```
mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(getCameraDisplayOrientation());    

private int getCameraDisplayOrientation()
    {
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK,
                info);
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation)
        {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
        {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
        } else
        { // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;

        }

        return result;
```

The Activity is defined in the manifest like that:

```
    <activity android:name="pages.CameraPage"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
      android:screenOrientation="landscape"
      >
    </activity>
```

The problem is that getCameraDisplayOrientation always returns 0 degrees, no matter how I orient the screen.

I call the method just before the record starts so if I would be able to get the rotation of the screen with respect to the default landscape I'd be ok.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your activity is fixed to landscape, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I've specified it in the manifest because ANdroid Developers advisec so to deal easily with the camera

Comment: This is why getCameraDisplayOrientation() does not change. But even when the activity orientation is fixed, you can check the accelerometer to derive the device orientation.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I was able to build successfully my own camera app without any orientation problem. The key was looking at the surfaceView for the rotation. I think it might help someone to have all the code posted here, just copy it and launch the Activity!

CameraPage.java

```
package pages;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;

import model.CameraView;

import com.controller.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class CameraPage extends Activity
{
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraView mPreview;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private FrameLayout preview;
    private ImageButton buttonRecordStop;
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private String fileName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("CameraPage-onCreate", "Called onCreate()");

        setContentView(R.layout.camera_surface);

        buttonRecordStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.camera_surface_buttonRecordStop);

        buttonRecordStop.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(1.0F, 0.3F);
                    alpha.setDuration(100);
                    alpha.setFillAfter(true); // Tell it to persist after the animation ends
                    buttonRecordStop.startAnimation(alpha);
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
                {
                    AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.3F, 1.0F);
                    alpha.setDuration(100);
                    alpha.setFillAfter(true); // Tell it to persist after the animation ends
                    buttonRecordStop.startAnimation(alpha);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        buttonRecordStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (!isRecording)
                {
                    Log.d("CameraPage-buttonRecordStop-onClick", "Start Record");

                    getWindow().addFlags(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                    // initialize video camera
                    if (prepareVideoRecorder())
                    {
                        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        ((ImageButton) v)
                                .setImageResource(R.drawable.iconapause);
                        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        isRecording = true;

                        // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                        // now you can start recording
                        mMediaRecorder.start();

                    } else
                    {
                        // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                        releaseMediaRecorder();
                        // inform user
                    }

                } else
                {
                    Log.d("CameraPage-buttonRecordStop-onClick", "Stop Record");

                    getWindow().clearFlags(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ((ImageButton) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.iconarecord);
                    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    isRecording = false;

                    stopRecording();

                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                            Uri.parse("file://"
                                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));


                }

            }// end onClick
        });

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

    }// end onCreate


    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("CameraPage-onResume",
                "Chiamato onResume ripristino le risorse se necessario");

        if (mCamera == null)
        {
            // Create an instance of Camera
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        }

        if (mPreview == null)
        {
            mPreview = new CameraView(getApplicationContext(), mCamera, this);
            preview.addView(mPreview);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("CameraPage-onPause", "Vado in onPause e rilascio le risorse");

        releaseMediaRecorder(); // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
        releaseCamera(); // release the camera immediately on pause event

        preview.removeView(mPreview);
        mPreview = null;
    }

    private void stopRecording()
    {
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        releaseMediaRecorder();

        // Restarto la preview della camera
        mCamera.startPreview();
        // mCamera.lock();
    }

    private boolean prepareVideoRecorder()
    {

        // mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        // Stop preview because I have to start the preview for the video
        mCamera.stopPreview();

        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        // Step 2: Set sources
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

        // Step 4: Set output file
        setOutputFile();
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputFile());

        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(CameraPage
                .getCameraDisplayOrientation(this,
                        Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, mCamera));

        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try
        {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            Log.d("CameraPage-prepareVideoRecorder",
                    "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: "
                            + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d("CameraPage-prepareVideoRecorder",
                    "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder()
    {
        if (mMediaRecorder != null)
        {
            mMediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mMediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera()
    {
        if (mCamera != null)
        {
            mCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }

        if (mPreview != null)
            mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);
    }

    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    private Camera getCameraInstance()
    {
        Camera c = null;
        try
        {
            Log.d("CameraPage-getCameraInstance", "Prendo istanza camera");
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
            Log.d("CameraPage-getCameraInstance",
                    "Eccezione durante retrieve istanza camera " + e);
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private void setOutputFile()
    {
        String folderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File vims = new File(folderPath + "/ViMS");

        if (!vims.exists())
            vims.mkdir();

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd---HH-mm-ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String timestamp = "/" + dateFormat.format(date) + ".mp4";

        Log.d("CameraPage-getOutputFile", Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());

        fileName = vims.getPath() + timestamp;

    }

    private String getOutputFile()
    {
        return fileName;
    }

    public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
            int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera)
    {

        int result = CameraPage.getCameraDisplayOrientation(activity, cameraId,
                camera);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 14)
        {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
            camera.startPreview();
        } else
        {
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
        }

    }// end setCameraDisplayOrientation

    public static int getCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
            int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera)
    {
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation)
        {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
        {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
        } else
        { // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        Log.d("CameraPage-onDestroy", "Called onDestroy");

    }

}// end CameraPage
```

CameraView.java

```
package model;

import java.io.IOException;

import pages.CameraPage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;




/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Activity activity;

    public CameraView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        Log.d("CameraView-default constructor",
                "Chiamato uno dei due default constructors");
    }

    public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        Log.d("CameraView-default constructor",
                "Chiamato uno dei due default constructors");
    }

    public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera, Activity activity)
    {
        super(context);
        Log.d("CameraView-constructor",
                "Inizializzo la classe con la camera e il context");

        this.activity = activity;

        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        Log.d("CameraView-surfaceCreated",
                "La superfice è stata creata, setto la preview della camera sulla superficie");

        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try
        {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d("CameraView-surfaceCreated", "Error setting camera preview: "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        Log.d("CameraView-surfaceDestroyed",
                "Distrutta superficie della preview");
        // Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h)
    {
        Log.d("CameraView-surfaceChanged",
                "Gestisco i cambiamenti nella superficie che ospita la camera");
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null)
        {
            // preview surface does not exist
            Log.d("CameraView-surfaceChanged", "Preview surface doesn't exist");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            CameraPage.setCameraDisplayOrientation(activity,
                    Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, mCamera);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("CameraView-surfaceChanged",
                    "Exception reorienting the camera " + e);
        }

    }// end surfaceChanged
}// end CameraView
```

camera_surface.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/camera_surface_buttonRecordStop"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/iconarecord" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Activity has been tested from Android 2.3.6 to 4.3. If you find any problem or have any suggestion please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is associated with your rotation variable, you may consider looking at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553650/how-to-check-device-natural-default-orientation-on-android-i-e-get-landscape). The main difference to pull away from that link is a `WindowManager` object is created and then used to get the rotation. This seemingly small difference has been the difference maker between a piece of my code working and not working.

You can simply say `Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();` and `Camera.getCameraInfo(...);`.

I am curious as to why you are specifying `CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK` in `android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, info);` I feel like you could just call `info.facing` to get the `int` instead.

I hope between the link and my suggestions/inquiries that something sparks the correct answer!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but still it is not working. The problem is with the activity fixed in the landscape mode in the manifest. If I remove it I can get the correct orientation even with my method but I need something which works in landscape